# diskpart error reading from file

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have the following code that works fine up to the last line in DskPrt1.txt `assign letter=`. The file gets written as it should. In a dropdownlist, I choose a drive letter, send the chosen letter to `FILE fp`, write it out and then direct diskpart to read it. This is the output

> Volume 1 is the selected volume
>
> the arguments specified for this command are not valid.

This tells me it is doing everything up until the second line in DskPrt.txt. I have copied and pasted the `assign letter=X` into diskpart manually and it runs just fine. Why doesn't it work with my code?

Part 1

```
SendMessage( 
(HWND) hWndDropMenu,    // handle to destination window 
CB_GETLBTEXT,           // message to send
(WPARAM) wParam,        // not used; must be zero
(LPARAM)tmpMsg          // not used; must be zero
);
```

Part 2

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("DskPrt1.txt", "wt");
char DskPrt11[] = "select volume 1";
char DskPrt12[] = "assign letter=";
fwrite (DskPrt11 , 1 , sizeof(DskPrt11) , fp );         //Line 1
fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), 1, fp);                      //New line
fwrite (DskPrt12 , 1 , sizeof(DskPrt12) , fp );         //Line 2
fwrite (tmpMsg , 1 , sizeof(tmpMsg) , fp );             //Letter
fclose(fp);

//Execute part 1 commands
std::wstring arrString[3] = {L"/C mkdir C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\test",L"/C DISKPART /s C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\DskPrt1.txt"};
LPWSTR cmd =L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    STARTUPINFO info={sizeof(info)};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    CreateProcessW(cmd, &arrString[i][0], NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo);
    ::WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of this:

```
fwrite (DskPrt11 , 1 , sizeof(DskPrt11) , fp );
```

By using sizeof(), you're including the terminating null.  So your file ends up with at least two null bytes that you don't want.  Use strlen() instead.

Comment: This works only now it is not writing the selected character. If I select "G" it writes "A" to the file. If I choose "N" it assigns "B".

Comment: That's because your SendMessage call is wrong.  In your comments you say wParam must be zero but that's not true.  wParam must be the index of the listbox item you want to retrieve.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx